# Is it ok to organize the labels this way?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, dataset, image-processing

I'm a beginner with ML and I am trying to create models to classify whether an image from venus contains volcanoes using this dataset:
https://www.kaggle.com/fmena14/volcanoesvenus

The labels are inside a csv file that contains four columns:

> **Volcano?: if in the image there are volcanoes (Main target), 1 or 0.**
>
> **for Volcano?=0 these three next features are NaN**
>
> **Type: 1= definitely a volcano,2 =probably, 3= possibly, 4= only a pit is visible**
>
> **Radius: is the radius of the volcano in the center of the image, in pixels**
>
> **Number Volcanoes: The number of volcanoes in the image**

I didn't really understand why the "Volcano?" column exists because it makes more sense to add a label with value 0 to the "Type" column and then fill Nan values if the type is 0.

So I thought it can be better to change it but and I wasn't sure if maybe there is a reason behind it or if it will affect the model somehow when training.

Is it okay to change the labels this way? Will it change something?

By the way,I am planning to use a neural network with convolutional layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do.

- If you aim to plain binary classification, keep only the first label and drop everything else.
- You can also make some sort of probability regression using the second layer as well (more like an ordered classification problem). If you choose this path, one simple way is to transform those first 5 columns in one and only numerical label.
- If you want to do object detection, then you may want to use the full set of labels to define your loss function.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I want to create a model to classify the first two columns - if it is a volcano or not, and its type. Isn't it a multiclass classification problem? What do you mean with transform those 5 columns in one and only numerical label?

Comment: And I thought to create a regression model separately to predict the radius of the volcanoes.

Comment: I mean that not finding any volcano, when there is one that's clearly visible (type 1) is worse than mistaking a type 2 volcano for a type 3 one, at least that seems to me like a quite slight difference. Also, you may want to allow your model to give predictions in between the classes, as they sit on a graded range, they are not classes that stand apart from each other.

Comment: So the simplest solution is to adopt a numerical label with value 0 when no volcano is present, 1 when there is only a pit... and 4 for "type 1" volcanos. There are various alternatives, search "ordinal classification/regression"

Comment: Oh, now I understand. I will search more about it, Thanks!